# problem booting up computer

Tags: boot

I tried to restart my linux computer and it is failing to boot up. It is showing a black screen with the error message "/dev/nvme0n1p2:clean". What is going wrong and what do I need to do to successfully boot up the computer?

Comment: Is this restart just after an install?  Can you switch to a virtual terminal (ctrl+alt+F4 then login)?  Look in /var/log/syslog for any errors (either from a virt term or from booting an install media in Try mode and mounting the root).